# Use jQuery buttons to update circle layers in a Leaflet map but getting 'eachLayer is not a function' when clicking on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have 18 buttons defined with values like "Architecture" and am testing them against the equivalent values in a CSV column for which I've used p5.js to define a variable as `disciplines`. The plan is to show only the circles on the Leaflet map for the selected button, but when I click on a button the console returns `eachLayer is not a function`. I'm pretty new to both jQuery and Leaflet, and am not getting how to work with layers.

```
circle = L.circle([latitudes[i], longitudes[i]], {
  color: "T", // the dot stroke color
  fillColor: ellipseColor, // the dot fill color fill
  Opacity: 0.5, // use some transparency so we can see overlaps
  radius: 25,
});


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    console.log("buttonpressed");
    var selectedGroup = $(this).val();
    circle.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      if (selectedGroup === 0) {
        mymap.addLayer(layer);
      } else if (layer.disciplines[i] !== selectedGroup) {
        // If the layer's id is different from the selected one, remove it from the map
        mymap.removeLayer(layer);
      } else {
        // Otherwise add it to the map
        mymap.addLayer(layer);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So what's the `circle` variable, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for  responding. This is the circle variable.         circle = L.circle([latitudes[i], longitudes[i]], {
            color: 'T',      // the dot stroke color
            fillColor: ellipseColor, // the dot fill color
            fillOpacity: 0.5,  // use some transparency so we can see overlaps
            radius: 25
        });

Comment: OK, now read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circle and tell me: Does the `L.Circle` class have a `eachLayer()` method?

Comment: Thanks. No it does not, but the code that I'm adapting (from a school project)  used CircleMarker, which also doesn't seem to have an eachLayer() method. That code is as follows (I believe this is the relevant part).   points = L.geoJson(pointsData, {
   style: style,
   pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng);

   },
   onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }).addTo(map);

Comment: That was a `L.GeoJSON` (which spawned `L.CircleMarker`s) and not a `L.Circle`. Apparently you're not grouping your `L.Circle`s in any fashion (a `L.LayerGroup` could be helpful). But, as of now, I think that your question is confusing, I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then editing your question to rephrase.

Comment: The `L.LayerGroup` is what I needed so thanks for that. I'll try to make my questions clearer in the future. Cheers.